# comparing an element in a column in a data frame with another element in the same column in another data frame for corresponding rows in R

Tags: r

I am new to programming and obviously new to R. I am learning some documents in R and started programming in R.

I have four data frames with data frame names `Data1`, `Data2`, `Data3`, `Data4`. Each data frames has eight columns (`V1`, `V2`, `V3`, `V4`, `V5`, `V6`, `V7`, `V8`) and 10,000 rows.The number of rows and number of columns is same for all the data frames.

I want to compare the elements of each row's 8th column (`V8`) of all the four data frame with each other with their corresponding rows and find the maximum and minimum value. For example if I have 10 rows and 8 columns in each data frame, I have to compare the 1st row 8th column element of `Data1`, `Data2`, `Data3`, `Data4` to find the maximum and minimum value. Then i have to compare the 2nd row 8th column element of `Data1`, `Data2`, `Data3`, `Data4` to find the maximum and minimum value. Similary the 3rd row 8th column element, 4th row 8th column element and i have to do this for remaining 10,000 rows. How should I do this and what function should I use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). A good reproducible example will help others to tackle your question lot more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data:

```
Data1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(80), 10, 8))
Data2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(80), 10, 8))
Data3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(80), 10, 8))
Data4 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(80), 10, 8))
```

You can do:

```
pmin(Data1$V8, Data2$V8, Data3$V8, Data4$V8)
pmax(Data1$V8, Data2$V8, Data3$V8, Data4$V8)
```

Or something more programmatic (there can be many variations here)

```
Datas <- mget(paste0("Data", 1:4))
do.call(pmin, lapply(Datas, `[[`, "V8"))
do.call(pmax, lapply(Datas, `[[`, "V8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine your columns in a new dataframe. Then its easy to find the row-wise min or max values:

```
newd <- data.frame(a=Data1$V8, b=Data2$V8, c=Data3$V8, d=Data4$V8)
apply(newd, 1, max)
```